# How to exclude packages or a few files within a package from test coverage?

Tags: go, code-coverage, test-coverage

I have a package in my Go repo which only has POJOs in it. I want to exclude the entire package from test coverage.

Can anyone please help me in ignoring the entire package from test coverage?

Comment: You mean POGOs? ;)

Comment: If it has no tests, it won't get test results, and therefore won't get coverage results from `go test -cover`.